# How to pass data to breeze Savechanges method for testing manually without binding to UI

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have to test whether the breeze `saveChanges` method is working.For that I am trying to pass a json array in the post method of breeze but when I check the post method in controller it says the `saveBundle` is null.
How can I test the `saveChanges` manually by passing any entities or json object  without actually binding to the view?

```
var SaveBundle = [{}];
var option = new breeze.SaveOptions({ resourceName: 'SaveChanges'})
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager;
var postData = function () {
    return manager.saveChanges(SaveBundle, option)
         .then(saveSucceeded)
         .fail(saveFailed);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to pass Breeze object using fiddler or other tools.

check below simple Example:

This is my Entity :

```
Class Test{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Json String:

```
{"entities":[{"Id":-1,"Name":"TestName",entityAspect":{"entityTypeName":"Test:#TestProject.Model.Data","defaultResourceName":"Test","entityState":"Added","originalValuesMap":{},"autoGeneratedKey":{"propertyName":"Id","autoGeneratedKeyType":"Identity"}}}],"saveOptions":{}}
```